# Buen día, tengo un bug raro en el momento de compilar el programa

Tags: java

```
 do{
        do{
            System.out.print("opc 1 ");
            System.out.print("Seleccione ");
            opc = n.nextInt();
                switch(opc){
                case 1 : 
                    do{
                       System.out.print("Seleccione ");
                       opc = n.nextInt();                
                        switch(opc){
                        case 1: crearPersonasNaturales(); break;
                        case 2 : crearCuentaVirtual(); break;
                        case 3 : listaDePersonasDelBanco(); break;
                        case 4 : verListaDelBanco(); break;
                        case 5 : ingresarCuenta();break;
                        case 6 : salir = true; 
                        default : System.out.print("Solo se puede escribir hasta la opcion 6");
                    }
                    }while(opc<6);
                    break;
            }
        }while(opc<4);
        System.out.print("¿Quiere salir del programa?, digite S para confirmar"
                + " o N para negar");
        digitar = n.next().charAt(0);
    }while(digitar == 'n' || digitar == 'N');
}
```

este es el main. Y el metodo que me arroja un bug es este (pero antes de ese metodo, hay otro, que me permite crear una persona natural):

```
 public static void crearPersonasNaturales(){
        System.out.println(">>Persona natural a crear<<");
        nombre = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nombres: ");
        nombre = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Apellidos: ");
        apellido = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Edad: ");
        edad = n.nextInt();
        ciudadNatal = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Ciudad: ");
        ciudadNatal = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Correo electronico: ");
        correoElectronico = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Cedula: ");
        nCedula = n.nextLine();
        personaN = new PersonaNatural(nombre, apellido, correoElectronico, ciudadNatal
        , nCedula, edad);
        agregarPersonasNaturales(personaN);
}
```

Las agrego en un arrayList de la misma, luego hago una confirmación antes de crear un nuevo usuario de un banco virtual (que es la edad) :

```
public static boolean confirmarEdad(){
    System.out.print("Digite su edad: ");
    edad = n.nextInt();
    boolean mayor = false;
    if(edad<18){
        System.out.println("No tienes la suficiente edad "
                + "para crearte una cuenta :(");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Si tiene la edad "
                + "suficiente :)");
        mayor = true;
    }
    return mayor;
}
```

Y finalmente el metodo para crear una nueva cuenta virtual, cabe recalcar que lo estoy creando, si es que existe esa persona natural, lo afirmo, pasandole el numero de cedula (eh ahí me marca el bug, ya que si pongo el número de cedula existente, me salen los nombres de la persona, me afirma que es mayor de edad, pero, me vuelve a repetir el ciclo, me vuelve a pedir numero de cedula, ya intente cambiando el valor del boolean, pero sigue el mismo bug), si no entienden algo, haganmelo saber y con gusto le responderé la duda, gracias. A continuación el metodo:

```
public static void crearCuentaVirtual(){
  if(confirmarEdad() == true){
      do{
        nombre = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Escriba sus nombres: ");
        nombre = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Escriba sus apellidos: ");
        apellido = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Escriba su ciudad: ");
        ciudadNatal = n.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Escriba su correo electronico: ");
        correoElectronico = n.nextLine();
        do{
        System.out.print("Escriba su número de cedula: ");
        nCedula = n.nextLine();
            Iterator<PersonaNatural>it = listaDePersonasN.iterator();
                if(it.hasNext()){
                    PersonaNatural p = it.next();
                         if(p.getCedula().equalsIgnoreCase(nCedula)){
                        System.out.println("Su nombre es: " + p.getNombres()
                        + " " + p.getApellidos());
                        salir = true;
                        if(p.getEdad() > 18){
                            System.out.println("Se comprobó que es mayor de edad");
                            salir = true;
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("Hey!, aún eres menor de edad mmv");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        if(!(p.getNombres().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre) && p.getApellidos().equalsIgnoreCase(apellido)
                            && p.getCiudadNatal().equalsIgnoreCase(ciudadNatal) && p.getCorreoElectronico().equalsIgnoreCase(correoElectronico))){
                        System.out.println("Porfavor revisar bien los datos, no concuerdan con el número de cedula.");
                        salir = false;
                    }
                    }else if(!p.getCedula().equalsIgnoreCase(nCedula)){
                       System.out.println("No se encuentra ese número de cedula");
                       salir2 = false;
                    }
                    /*else{
                        System.out.println("No se encuentra ese número de cedula");
                       salir2 = false;
                    }*/
                }
        }while(salir2 == false);
      }while(salir == false);
        System.out.print("Escriba el numero de cuenta: ");
        nDeCuenta = n.nextInt();
        digiteContra();
        BancoVirtual b = new BancoVirtual(0,nDeCuenta,contra, nombre, apellido
        , ciudadNatal, correoElectronico, nCedula, edad);
        agregarPersonasBanco(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pusiste mucha informacion, y esta bien, pero pusiste demasiada y tu problema se pierde en todo el codigo que pusiste.. necesitamos un [mcve] o por lo menos, que identifiques claramente la parte problematica, y centres tu prgunta en eso..

Comment: xd :( si pongo poca, que muy poca xd jajaja, pero lo separé con una pequeña introducción a lo que hace el metodo que es. El problema central, es el bug al momento de crear una cuenta virtual, ya que me aseguro que exista la persona natural con el numero de cedula, pero le paso uno que existe y me vuelve a repetir el ciclo, como si no existiera esa cedula, pero si me imprime el nombre y apellido de tal cedula.

Comment: Muestrame justamente esa parte.. tenes dos loops, uno dentro de otro (no entiendo porque) y para mi, estas modificando la variable equivocada.. probaste seguir tu codigo, linea a linea, y ver que variable deberias cambiar en cada caso?

Comment: El valor predeterminado para un boolean es false ,si te percatas salir2 nunca cambia a true por ende tu dowhile se repite ,debes inicializar salir2 como true

Comment: @gbianchi pues tengo 2 loops porque, la primera si marca el error de que si no concuerdan los nombres y apellidos con el número de cédula, vuelve a repetir esa opción para que el usuario escriba bien, si te das cuenta mando un mensaje de:porfavor revisar bien los datos, y ahí con el boolean se vuelve a repetir automáticamente, pero te cuento que antes de meter el método al Main, todo jalaba bien, todo seguía bien y pues, luego de que arme esa lógica para unos menú de opciones, me salió ese bug

Comment: @Dramaturgo pero, como le digo a gbianchi, todo iba bien, la lógica me funcionaba de maravilla, antes de meterlo al método Main, pero intentaré igual cambiarle a true, a ver si se arregla el bug

Comment: se entiende,pero tu do while es claro mientras salir2 sea ==false se repetira ,para que salga del bucle debes inicializar `boolean salir2=true;` y solo cuando la `cedula` del objeto `p` sea diferente a `ncedula` salir2 tomara el valor de false y por ende se reptira el bucle

Comment: Bro, me salió otro problema :s, ya no me agrega personas en el banco virtual, al momento de saber cuantas tengo con un `listaPersonasBanco.size()`, me sale vacía, como si no hubiera agregado nada, y en la lista de persona natural, si lo crea :s (Eso tampoco me pasaba antes de meterlo en el main), tu crees que sea por el main? (lo dudo, pero a veces las respuestas son tontas que lo pienso xd)